# ¿Cómo recoger mis clientes + clientes de mis clientes ... ? en una sola Consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos que recoge a todos los clientes, esta tabla tiene una columna que se llama id_jefe. Pues yo quiero recoger a todos los clientes que tengan en id_jefe por ejemplo 1 (`SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id_jefe = 1`), pero al mismo tiempo es que ese cliente puede ser jefe de otro, por lo tanto también quiero que aparezcan esos clientes, y, por si no fuera poco, otra vez igual. En resumen hay tres niveles, cada nivel puede ver todo lo que tiene el nivel por debajo. No sé si me he explicado.

Por ahora la "solución" chapuza que he encontrado es hacer varias consultas con PHP, pero eso no es nada óptimo.
Esto es lo que ahora mismo tengo:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id_jefe={$_SESSION['id']}";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE id_jefe={$data['id']}";
        $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query2) > 0){
            while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){

                /*
                bla bla bla ....
                */

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

- Lo que quiero es que me devuelva EN UNA SOLA CONSULTA:
  mis clientes + los clientes de mis clientes + los clientes de los clientes de mis clientes

Comment: todos estan en la misma tabla?

Comment: Si la consulta llega a ser demasiado compleja y no eres capaz de visualizar los joins, puedes crear [un procedimiento o una función](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) donde se ejecuten todas las consultas en la base de datos y devuelva los datos que quieres. Gracias a los procedimientos y funciones, puedes ejecutar todo el código que quieras en la base de datos con sólo una consulta.